Occurence extrapolation/statistics in a set of incomplete collections
My statistics courses are a long way off now (I'm a biologist). My problem is probably trivial, but I don't know where to start.
My goal is to calculate the occurrence of a gene X in a set of genomes. Basically, what is the fraction of genomes that contains the gene of interest. The thing is that genomes are rarely complete. So if the gene X is not observed, it may be that it's actually not here or that it is in the missing data. But we can estimate the completeness of genomes, i.e. the percentage of genes detected. If possible, I would like to take this into account to get a corrected occurrence.
Here's a “translation” of the problem in non-biological terms.

Ci​ : The i-th collection (1 to n)
Si : The total number of elements in collection Ci​.
Ki : The number of known (non-missing) elements in Ci​​.
Mi : The number of missing elements in Ci​​.
XCi : An indicator variable, which is 1 if
element X is found in collection Ci​​ (in the known elements), and 0 otherwise.

The observed occurrence of X is :
$$ O_{obs}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{ci}}{n} $$
How to infer the real occurrence? Is there a way to assess the robustness of the inference or of the measured occurrence?
Thanks!

Welcome to Cross Validated ! I am having a lot of difficulty understanding you question. Can you edit it to fully explain your study design, your research hypothesis, how the data were collected, what analysis model you have in mind, and, since this seems to be a missing data problem, why there are missing values.

There are reliable ways to handle missing data when you have what's called "missing at random" (MAR) data in a technical sense; an "example of MAR is when we take a sample from a population, where the probability to be included depends on some known property." It sounds like that might be the case for you, but it's hard to know for sure without the extra information that @RobertLong requested. Please provide that by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Thank you for your quick replies! It's a bit hard for me to explain this in mathematical terms, sorry. I edited the question to add more information.

Two questions, one on biology and one on the technical method. First, how are you dealing with orthologs and paralogs when you determine whether the genome of a species "contains the gene of interest"? Second, do the underlying data come from whole-genome sequencing at low coverage (hence "missing" genes) or on some other technology? Again, please provide this information by editing the question. Biologists (like me) who frequent this site would need that information (preferably, with even more details) to provide a useful answer.

I'm also having a little trouble understanding the exact setup. I feel like there should be something here, but I can't quite get your notation down. Do you mean that "Si" is the number of genes you expect to detect and "Ki" was the number of those genes that you actually did detect?
